# Proper way to store user information

Tags: joomla, profile

The standard Joomla registration forms has a limited set of fields available.  What's the "correct" method for adding the user's first name, last name, and phone number to the registration project?  I can certainly modify the Joomla core, but that's less than ideal.

A nickel for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you'll need to code alternatives for `com_user` and `mod_login`, then store your extra information in a separate table, keyed by `user_id`. Community Builder does something similar, only on a much larger scale. There may also be other similar profile extensions that act as drop-in alternatives to the core login system.

Comment: Update: in Joomla 1.6+, there's a much cleaner way of accomplishing this: the user profile plugin. Take a look at the code in `plugins/user/profile` and make a similar plugin with a different name. Add your new fields to the XML and PHP files, then unpublish the original plugin and publish the new plugin. No core hacks :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it (and most in line with Joomla 1.6 - when it's released) is to use the Joomla User Meta plugin. [UserMeta](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/usermeta/)

You can extend the profile using just the user xml file but this won't store them in a database, merely as parameters. The Usermeta is much more robust.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by using the [CBE](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communities-a-groupware/communities/6155) extension for Joomla!  Depending on your needs that might be overkill for you, but if you need profile management with avatars and other features you can consider going that route.